# Angular animations: on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

I have a problem animating some elements in my Angular application.
There is a grid composed of cells (generated with a ng-repeat).
What I want to do is create a simple animation: on click, the cell should disappear (fadeOut effect for instance) and reappear after a while.

I've managed to do a fadeOut effect following [this tutorial](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html#rolling-out-animations-with-your-own-directives)

Here is the code that manages the cells:

```
      <div class="col col-20 cell" style="background-image:url('img/gray.png')">
          <img class="cell-img" ng-src="{{cells[$index].getSrc()}}" width="100%" ng-click="click(cells[$index])" cell-click/>
       </div>
      <div class="col col-20 cell" style="background-image:url('img/gray.png')">
          <img class="cell-img" ng-src="{{cells[$index + 1].getSrc()}}" width="100%" ng-click="click(cells[$index + 1])" cell-click/>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-20 cell" style="background-image:url('img/gray.png')">
          <img class="cell-img" ng-src="{{cells[$index + 2].getSrc()}}" width="100%" ng-click="click(cells[$index + 2])" cell-click/>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-20 cell" style="background-image:url('img/gray.png')">
          <img class="cell-img" ng-src="{{cells[$index + 3].getSrc()}}" width="100%" ng-click="click(cells[$index + 3])" cell-click/>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-20 cell" style="background-image:url('img/gray.png')">
          <img class="cell-img" ng-src="{{cells[$index + 4].getSrc()}}" width="100%" ng-click="click(cells[$index + 4])" cell-click/>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```js
app.controller("Control", function($scope, $interval, ...){
  $scope.click = function(cell){
    if($scope.gameStarted){
      if(cell.isActive){
        if(colorOk){
          // ...
        }
        else{
          // ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: why don't you simply use jQuery to achieve your goal?

Answer (score 0):

You can use $timeout to make the cell reappear after a certain time after you hide it.

Something like:

```
$timeout(function () {
    //code to make the cell appear/show the cell (maybe by removing ng-hide class)
  }, 1000);
```